# Error: Fedora-22 chroot doesn't have yum

Tags: fedora, chroot, fedora-core

I am trying to create fedora-22 chroot using mock. The command I am using is:

```
mock -r ${distro}-${arch} --init
```

When I pass fedora-22 as distro, and I enter the shell I am not able to do yum install. It says, "Yum: command not found".

I am not sure how to proceed next if I can't install anything in that chroot. I mean, to install don't you need yum already?!

Could you please help me resolve the issue? TIA

Comment: Maybe because fedora 22 switched to dnf.. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ReplaceYumWithDNF + https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock?rd=Subprojects/Mock#Mock_on_EL_6_and_EL_7:_Yum.2C_and_DNF

Comment: Yeah, because of that only, I just realized!

Answer (score 0):

So, this was because Fedoraa 22 moved to dnf.